# How to use google mlkit outside an Android app in a regular Kotlin project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, aar, google-mlkit

I'm new to kotline and android development.

I have an app that will use [mlkit v2 text recognization](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/v2/android), but first I'd like to run the API on a bunch of images on my laptop to assess its quality. Because doing this inside an Android emulator or my phone is cumbersome as I'll need to copy the many images to the emulator or phone first, so I created a regular kotlin project with gradle as the build system in Intellij (NOT Android Studio) and tried to create a script that can call the mlkit v2 API. However, I noticed the downloaded dependencies are `aar` instead of `jar`, and

```
import com.google.mlkit.vision.text.TextRecognition
```

does **NOT** work. So I wonder if it's possible to use the mlkit v2 outside an Android app at all? If so, what's the recommended way, please?